# Combine two or More contiguous Ranges into Single Multi-Area Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a Utility **AddIn** for Excel which deals with variable number of **Ranges**. It can modify the **Current Selection** or create **New selections** for further use: such as to apply **Formatting Styles**, **Merge** and **Un-Merge**.

In this AddIn, i need to combine many Contiguous ranges into one "**Multi-Area Range**" say:

```
"A1:A10","A11:A20","A21:A30",......."A490:A500"
```

To do that' if ranges are fewer, I use "**Range**" method e.g.:

```
Addr="A1:A10,A11:A20,A21:A30"
Set Rng=Range(Addr)
```

It works fine and create one "**Multi-Area Range**", where:

```
Rng.Areas.Count       'is 3
Rng.Areas(1).address  'is "$A$1:$A$10"
Rng.Areas(2).address  'is "$A$11:$A$20"
Rng.Areas(3).address  'is "$A$21:$A$30"
```

But **problem** begins when the **length of address** parameter is **more then 255**. At this situation "Range" fails and
throws an error: i.e.

```
Addr="A1:A10,A11:A20,A21:A30,A31:A40,A41:A50,A51:A60,A" & _
    "61:A70,A71:A80,A81:A90,A91:A100,A101:A110,A111:A" & _
    "120,A121:A130,A131:A140,A141:A150,A151:A160,A161" & _
    ":A170,A171:A180,A181:A190,A191:A200,A201:A210,A2" & _
    "11:A220,A221:A230,A231:A240,A241:A250,A251:A260," & _
    "A261:A270,A271:A280,A281:A290,A291:A300,A301:A31" & _
    "0,A311:A320,A321:A330,A331:A340,A341:A350,A351:A" & _
    "360,A361:A370,A371:A380,A381:A390,A391:A400,A401" & _
    ":A410,A411:A420,A421:A430,A431:A440,A441:A450,A4" & _
    "51:A460,A461:A470,A471:A480,A481:A490,A491:A500"
    Set Rng=Range(Addr)
```

Error thrown: "**Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed**"

To overcome this limitation of "**Range**" Method, i used "**Union**" Function:

```
Set rng = Union( _
    Range("A1:A10,A11:A20,A21:A30,A31:A40,A41:A50,A51:A60"), _
    Range("A61:A70,A71:A80,A81:A90,A91:A100,A101:A110,A111:A120"), _
    Range("A121:A130,A131:A140,A141:A150,A151:A160,A161:A170"), _
    Range("A171:A180,A181:A190,A191:A200,A201:A210,A211:A220"), _
    Range("A221:A230,A231:A240,A241:A250,A251:A260,A261:A270"), _
    Range("A271:A280,A281:A290,A291:A300,A301:A310,A311:A320"), _
    Range("A321:A330,A331:A340,A341:A350,A351:A360,A361:A370"), _
    Range("A371:A380,A381:A390,A391:A400,A401:A410,A411:A420"), _
    Range("A421:A430,A431:A440,A441:A450,A451:A460,A461:A470"), _
    Range("A471:A480,A481:A490,A491:A500"))
```

It works **fine** with **Non-Contiguous** Ranges. But when all the ranges are Contiguous (as in my case) "**Union**" combines all ranges to one "**Single Area Range**". i.e.

```
Rng.Areas.Count       'is 1
Rng.Areas(1).Address  'is "$A$1:$A$500"
```

Where as i need a "Multi Area Range" for further uses, where.

```
Rng.Areas.Count       'Must be 50
Rng.Areas(1).Address  'Must be "$A$1:$A$10"
Rng.Areas(2).address  'Must be "$A$11:$A$20"
Rng.Areas(3).address  'Must be "$A$21:$A$30"
.......
.......
Rng.Areas(50).address 'Must be "$A$491:$A$500"
```

Unfortunately the "Range.Areas" property is readonly.
So i can not add or remove any element directly.

**Please help** me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not just use an **array** of contiguous ranges?

Comment: @YowE3K you are sharp today ;)  12 hours straight

Comment: If i use an Array How would i able to select the all ranges contained by Array on active sheet. e.g. "Rng.Select" will work. But "Rng(0).Select" will only select the 0th range. And when "Rng(1).Select" will be executed the the old selection (0th) will be unselected and 1st will be selected and so on. I am developing an AddIn which provides the advanced options to control current selection for further uses. for example it can: Expand or Shrink Selection, Move selection to up-down-left-right, Select Interval Ranges. It is working fine Until the Address is less than 255. or It is Non contiguous.

Comment: Why do you need to `Select` any of the ranges? Keeping an array of all the input ranges will certainly keep track of those ranges, contiguous or not. It's rare that you need to `Select` anything using VBA unless you're trying to highlight an area visually for the user.

Comment: Yes, it is a utility AddIn whose only purpose is to select ranges for the user, based on multiple criteria. That's why i need it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found any method to create such sophisticated range object in Excel, but I think desired by you behavior could be achieved by wrapping many ranges into 1 class object.
It is not ready solution, but the idea how it could be achieved. It has to be adjusted to your needs.

The idea is to wrap individual ranges into 1 class and then union ranges when needed.

Class code (i.e. MyRanges):

```
Option Explicit
Private ranges As New Collection
Public Sub Add(rng As Range)
     ranges.Add rng
End Sub
Property Get MyAreas()
    Set Areas = ranges
End Property
Public Sub Remove(rng As Range)
    ranges.Remove rng
End Sub
Public Function GetRanges(ParamArray indexes()) As Range
Dim res As Range
Dim i As Integer

    Set res = ranges(indexes(0))
    If UBound(indexes) = 0 Then
        Set GetRanges = res
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To UBound(indexes)
        Set res = Union(res, ranges(indexes(i)))
    Next i
    Set GetRanges = res

End Function
```

Test code for class:

```
Public Sub Test()
Dim Addr As String
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range, Rng5 As Range, Rng6 As Range
Dim ranges As MyRanges
Dim result As Range

    Addr = "A1:A10"
    Set Rng1 = Range(Addr)
    Addr = "A11:A20"
    Set Rng2 = Range(Addr)
    Addr = "A21:A30"
    Set Rng3 = Range(Addr)
    Addr = "A31:A40"
    Set Rng4 = Range(Addr)
    Addr = "A41:A50"
    Set Rng5 = Range(Addr)
    Addr = "A51:A60"
    Set Rng6 = Range(Addr)

    Set ranges = New MyRanges
    ranges.Add Rng1
    ranges.Add Rng2
    ranges.Add Rng3
    ranges.Add Rng4
    ranges.Add Rng5
    ranges.Add Rng6

    Set result = ranges.GetRanges(1, 2)
    Debug.Print result.Address
    Set result = ranges.GetRanges(1, 3, 5)
    Debug.Print result.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @smartobelix:

Comment: Hi @smartobelix: Thanks for the help, But it can not implemented in my case. Becoz `GetRanges()` uses `Union` to all ranges. which again combines all contiguous ranges to one range. and in this i could figure out the `Areas` in `Set Areas = ranges'. it is shown as undefined symbol.

Comment: Let me explain what i need:
Let `A1:A10` and `A11:A20` are ranges to be stored in single `R` object and finally perform a selection based on `R`. e.g.
`set R=Range("A1:A10,A11:A20")`
`R.Select`
it will select both ranges separately. for example if you merge the selection,
Ranges `A1:A10` and `A11:A20` will be merged separately. But when you use `Union`
it convert all contiguous or adjacent ranges to one ranges.
As the result when you merge the selection, Range `A1:A20` is get merged.

Comment: (Merging is just an example not the only task performed on selection, Otherwise it could be done VBA).

Some one suggested me: Avoid selection.
The one and only task performed by AddIn is "Selection". How can i Avoid this?

Currently i am combining the ranges using `Range` function, as long as the total string len is 255,
if len is greater then i use `Union` and Warn the user that rages are combined.

Comment: The class I proposed could be replacement of what you expect from Range object. Method GetRanges can be used for selecting and it is always creating temporary Range object containing all ranges you need. So the idea is not to use GetRanges, only enchance this class that it is providing required areas management. So you can add 20 adjancent ranges into MyRanges object and you will still have access to each individual range as well as through GetRanges method to any combination of those areas. Maybe you can post some sample code using Areas in Range that I could translate it to MyRange class.

Comment: Sir you r not getting my point. Why i would need to store them in a class (More specifically in collection)? They are already stored in an array. I can access them using index. This is the final stage of project where i need to: Make a `Selection` based on all these ranges stored in array on active sheet. In this selection all the ranges must be selected separately, regardless these are contiguous or non-contiguous. (Note: By `Selection` i mean `Visually Shown Selected Cells` on active sheet. Not stored in VBA data structures.

Comment: So if you have multiple ranges and want to make them Selected on worksheet, the only way `(that i know)` is: Step a) `Combine them to a single range object`. Step b) `Call the Select method of that object. i.e. Rng.Select`.

Comment: You can not call `Select` method separately for each range using loops or any similar tech. This will `Un-select` the previous range and make a selection for current range. At the end 'there is only last range remains selected.

Comment: Sadly I think there is no way to do this, through VBA. Thank you for your code. It was good but can not be implemented in my scenario or I don't know how to modify it for my specific need. It will be good if you can provide me the code to make selection for all the ranges stored in `ranges` collection of your `MyRanges` class. You may use any technique or trick you know.